# Old FPS world explorer game that occured in a dream while on a train

Tags: identify-this-game

This game is probably 20 years old FPS PC game. Has similar graphics as of Flashpoint Cold-war-Crisis, IGI-1, Mass-Effect-1, HALO-1.

**Weapons** - Mostly earthly based weapons, but also got magical weapons.
**Enemies** - Mostly zombie like magical characters.
**Mission maps** - From earth based normal/foggy/swamp/war-destroyed to alien worlds to completely magical worlds.

**Story-line** -

- The main character is on a train going to his brother's home.
- Train reaches the station, character gets out and reaches to his brother's home.
- During some chit-chats with his brother main character sees minor glitches(burning fires) for fraction of seconds. He ignores them.
- When his brother goes upstairs to bring some stuffs, those glitches worsens and remain longer. He gets curious. Now those glitches get permanent.
- He could not find his brother any more. Starts his search.
- Missions include earth based maps(of various conditions) and weapons at beginning, but later change to include low gravity magical alien planet like maps. And during end, completely magical maps and weapons.
- The last map has 2(or may be 4) angel like characters who are attacking you. The fight is happening in a magical dark world which has a square shaped(estimated to be 50x50 meters) arena without roof and whose 4 walls are broken. Those 2(or may be 4) angels are standing on each corners of the arena.
- After that mission, the main character wakes up in the train he was traveling, realising that he felt asleep and all these things were in his dream.
- He reaches his brother's home, no glitches this time. The game ends.

Though this game is old and not famous at all, this is the best game I have every played in my opinion.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate, but the description in the other question is different from this one.